# Why Do I keep getting 'undefined' when entering data from an html form to a database

Tags: html, sql, node.js, ejs

Need help with an error in mysql statement. Im trying to make a website that will add, edit and delete data from a database. When I enter the data in from the website the sql statement shows 'undefined' with the data that is supposed to altered.

I dont even know where to look. I've checked all the sql statements to see if it was an issue there.

```
{"code":"ER_TRUNCATED_WRONG_VALUE_FOR_FIELD","errno":1366,"sqlMessage":"Incorrect integer value: 'undefined' for column 'collegeID' at row 1","sqlState":"HY000","index":0,"sql":"Update College SET collegeName = 'undefined', CoAbbreviation = 'undefined', collegeID = 'undefined'"}
```

This is the entire error message when I am editing a table.

This is the code for editing the college.

```js
 editCollege: (req, res) => {

        let collegeID = req.params.id;
        let collegeName = req.body.collegeName;
        let CoAbbreviation = req.body.CoAbbreviation;
        // rewrite query later tonight 
        console.log(collegeID);

        //UPDATE College SET collegeName  = 'collegeName',
        //CoAbbreviation = 'CoAbbreviation' 
        //WHERE CollegeID = 'CollegeID';
        let editCollegeQuery = "Update College SET collegeName = " + "'" + collegeName + "'" + ', ' + "CoAbbreviation = " + "'" + CoAbbreviation + "'" + ', ' + "collegeID = " + "'" + collegeID + "'";
        console.log(editCollegeQuery);
        db.query(editCollegeQuery, (err, results) => {
            if(err){
                return res.status(500).send(err);
            }
            res.redirect('/');
        });
    },

    deleteCollege: (req,res) => {
        let collegeID = req.params.id;
        let deleteCollegeQuery = 'DELETE FROM College WHERE collegeID = "' + collegeID + '"';
        console.log(collegeID);

        db.query(deleteCollegeQuery, (err, results) => {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(500).send(err);
            }
            res.redirect('/');
        });

    }

};
```

Here are ether routes for the app

```
//routes for the app 
app.get('/', getHomePage);
app.get('/add', addCollegePage);
app.get('/edit/:id', editCollegePage);
app.get('/delete/:id', deleteCollege);
app.post('/add', addCollege);
app.post('/edit/:id', editCollege);
```

Here is the middleware

```
app.set('port', process.env.port || port); 
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views'); 
app.set('view engine', 'ejs'); // configture template engine 
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json()); //parse data from client
```

Front-end code for edit-college

```
<div class="container">
<% if (message) { %>
    <p class="text-center text-danger"><%= message %></p>
<% } %>

<% if (College) { %>
    <form class="edit-college-form" action="" method="post"                     enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <label for="collegeName">College Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control"   name="collegeName" id="collegeName" value="<%= College.collegeName%>" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <label for="CoAbbreviation"> College Abbreviation </label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="CoAbbreviation" id="CoAbbreviation" value="<%= College.CoAbbreviation %>" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success float-right">Update College</button>
    </form>
<% } else { %>
    <p class="text-center">College Not Found. Go <a                                     href="/add">here</a> to add College.</p>
<% } %>
</div>
</div>
</body>
 </html>
```

Comment: A value being passed from the web for/web page is most likely not being populated correctly client side.  Check the client side code which is returning the values used in you sql statement.

Comment: Also use the template literal e.g : 

**let deleteCollegeQuery = \`DELETE FROM College WHERE collegeID = ${collegeID}\`;**

Comment: @AnkurDubey that's not going to make it any better. OP should use the prepared statement syntax (assuming their DB library supports it)

Comment: @Phil I posted the routes,

Comment: @Subburaj what do you mean by their values?

Comment: Oh, it should be `req.params.id` (params, plural).

Comment: As for your other undefined values, how are you posting data to your server from the client-side?

Comment: @Phil I posted middleware

Comment: @Subburaj This is the output of what you asked.                                          undefined This is req.param.id
[object Object] This is req.body

Comment: @Phil so now I am getting a value for collegeID, but collegeName and Coabbrevaition is still undefined

Comment: @Subburaj Yes that worked for the collegeID! however the other data is still undefined

Comment: @Subburaj when I do that it will show it has 'undefined'

Comment: Post your frontend code how r u passing the req.body??

Comment: @Subburaj just posted it

Answer (score 1):

You have to do some corrections in your code. Firstly, its

```
let collegeID = req.params.id;//NOT req.param.id
```

Secondly, what result do you get on doing ??

```
console.log(req.body);
```

In case it is an object then your collegeName property is not their. Or in case of an  Array you should refer to the index of the Array.

**EDIT:** 
I read the comments below. If you are getting an undefined while console logging req.body then it means that the data has not passed from your html form. have you defined the name attribute inside the fields in the form??
Please share your HTML code in the question.

**EDIT**
Please add some route in form action attribute in your HTML code. Your form data is not going anywhere because it has no route where it should be sent. Please add in action

```
<form class="edit-college-form" action="/edit" method="post"                     enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: When I do console.log(req.body[0]) it will show undefined, I updated the params.id thanks for the help!

Comment: I saw your html code. Your action attribute is empty. Where are you posting this data??

Comment: Can you explain what you mean? Im sorry, Im fairly new to working with html and javascript.

Comment: Where does the route go? Would it go? Would it go 'editCollege' goes? Also, there is a <form action=""> in the html already.

Comment: Route will take you to the middeware where you have a function in which you are calling req.body. By route I mean the url. In your case I guess it is "/edit". So, it would be <form class="edit-college-form" action="/edit" method="post"                     enctype="multipart/form-data">

Comment: Thank you for all of your help, I think I just need to figure out the route I need to use. It says "cannot post /routes/college.js" Which is what I thought it would go to